# Ubuntu server connection issue

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I'm having problems with my server. The server info is below. The problem I'm having it just started a few days ago after a server restart. I use in my php code

```
@get_headers($url);
```

I'm also using Google recaptcha. The problem I'm having is when my server outbound connections run real slow. I don't timeout it just takes about 10 seconds to get a header request or to connect to google recaptcha. I tried pinging out of the machine it works but each ping takes for ever not to ping but to start. I checked the name servers and there fine and there the same on my other two servers that are under the same network. My question is where do I start or what commands do I need to enter to trouble shoot this.

Thank you

Server Info:

```
Ubuntu Linux 11.10
Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.7 
Kernel and CPU: Linux 3.0.0-19-server on x86_64
```

Comment: Please add more detail surrounding "I checked the name servers and there fine"

Comment: @wfaulk In my etc/resolv.conf folder there the same nameservers as my other two boxes and there fine and there under the same network.

Comment: I was hoping for the results from a `dig` or equivalent.  Also, "they're", not "there".

Comment: For some reason it's working now. Also I understand my grammar is bad you understand me though. It's hard I didn't really finish school. I got my G.E.D. What can I say though bad grammar being 25 and retired since I got lucky on the internet. Sorry man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this happen when reverese DNS lookups time out.  You might want to check that the `*.in-addr.arpa.` zones are properly configured for your DNS servers.

You may also want to test just doing a simple reverse lookup of the connecting hosts from the servers, e.g. `host 192.168.1.1` if you have a client "192.168.1.1" attempting to connect

It could help to make sure reverse lookups are turned off in apache via httpd.conf:

```
HostnameLookups Off
```

Comment: I checked apache2.conf and "HostnameLookups Off" is off already. I only use A records and vhost. The name servers are configured just like the other two boxes. They do not have a problem. I will try to see how to check "*.in-addr.arpa." zones. Thank you

Comment: Could it be something to do with dns caching? Are you running `nscd` on all three servers?

Comment: I'm not using "nscd" just checked.